# Passing muliple values ssrs sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008

I have the following sql:

```
--DECLARE @absent nvarchar(20)
--SET @absent = 'Y' -- Not needed in sql as we are setting this in ssrs

SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Absent in @Absent
```

Here is the employees table.

```
Employee 
Name Absent 
Dan    Y
Laura  N
Ross   N
James  Y
```

I want to be able to filter between Y and N and both.

This is working fine for me in SSRS when I pass @absent both Y and N. However, when i convert to a stored procedure and run in SSRS, I now get an issue. I longer get any results.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetEmployees
@Absent nvarchar(20)

    SELECT * 
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Absent in @Absent
```

I've tried the line `=join(parameters!Absent.value,",")` in the parameter properties but no luck. I believe the issue is with the data type that is being passed in. It is just odd that it works before i converted to a usp.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code wouldn't work directly in SQL.  You can fix it using parentheses:

```
 WHERE Absent in (@Absent)
```

This is exactly equivalent to:

```
WHERE Absent = @Absent
```

which is probably not what you intend.  In the more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use:

```
WHERE Absent IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@Absent, ','))
```

The `','` is my guess at the separator you are using.  You can also use:

```
WHERE ',' + @Absent + ',' LIKE '%,' + Absent + ',%'
```

Comment: Thank you, WHERE ',' + @Absent + ',' LIKE '%,' + Absent + ',%' worked for me :))

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you had a typo in your question and you meant to write

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Absent in (@Absent)
```

The reason that this WILL work when used directly in a dataset query is that SSRS will take your multi-valued parameter's selected options, convert them into a comma separated list and inject them into the SQL. So what will actually be executed will be, for example,

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Absent in ('Y', 'N')
```

This process is not the same when calling a stored procedure as SSRS cannot change the code inside your SP.

When passing multi-value parameters to a Stored Proc you would typically pass in an expression such as `=JOIN(Parameters!myParam.Value, ",")` . This passes in a string containing a comma separated list of your selected parameter values.

Inside the Stored Proc you would typically call a function to split this string back out into a table that you can join to.

There are plenty or articles describing this and providing a usable `split` function in case you don't have one. Check out the answers here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ead7ceb-3fdd-4625-aa82-1d4195f984b1/passing-multivalue-parameter-in-stored-procedure-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 1):

With SSRS, if using a Stored Procedure, the format `Column IN (@Variable)` doesn't work. That type of query *only* works if the SQL in directly in the SSRS Data Set's definition. Then SSRS will replace the value of `@Variable` and (apparently) securely inject the values in a delimited and quoted list.

For something as simple this, you are, in truth, better off likely just putting the below statement in the dataset in SSRS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Absent in (@Absent);
```

If not, and you need to use a Stored Procedure, then SSRS passes a delimited string as the parameter. In such cases you need to use a splitter. Considering you tag BIDS ([visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008)) then you need to use a really old way of doing this. I also strongly recommend you look at upgrade paths ASAP.

For 2008, then I recommend [`delimitedsplit8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) (or `delimitedsplitN4K` if using an `nvarchar`). Then your Procedure will look like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetEmployees @Absent nvarchar(4000) AS
BEGIN

    SELECT E.* --YOu should replace this with your actual columns
    FROM Employee E
         JOIN dbo.delimitedsplitN4K(@Absent,',') DS ON E.Absent = DS.item;
END;
```